# Don't pollute outside context when solving equation from the outside

Tags: functions, hold, scoping

This code works fine only if `a` is not defined in the outside context:

```
getA[f_,total_]:=Module[{},
    result=Solve[\!\(
     \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(255\)]\(f \[DifferentialD]i\)\)==total,a];
     If[Length[result] == 0,Return[False]];
     a/.First@result//N
];
plotShow[f_,max_]:=Module[{},
    a=getA[f,max];
    If[!a,Return[]];
    Print[f];
    Plot[f,{i,0,255}]
];

plotShow[i * a, 3500] (* => 0.107651 i      & a plot*)
(* Now showPlot has polluted the outside context with a = 0.107651 *)
plotShow[i * a, 3500] (* => Solve::ivar: "0.107651 is not a valid variable." *)
```

How can I make the function `plotShow` stop polluting the outside context?

Comment: @PinguinDirk Yes that fixed it, thank you!

Comment: (I commented to repleace `plotShow[f_,max_]:=Module[{},...]` by `plotShow[f_,max_]:=Block[{a},...]` - this is ok only as long as `a` is empty)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in my comment above, here's a way that works even if `a` and/or `i` have global values:

```
getA[f_, total_] := Module[{result},
    result = Solve[Integrate[f[a, i], {i, 0, 255}] == total, a];
    If[Length[result] == 0, Return[False]];
    a /. First@result // N
];

plotShow[f_, max_] := Block[{a, i},
    a = getA[f, max];
    If[! a, Return[]];
    Print[f[a, i]];
    Plot[f[a, i], {i, 0, 255}]
];

f[a_, i_] := i a
plotShow[f, 3500]
```

I tried not to modify most of your code, just the `Block` is new and so is the declaration of `f`. I hope this helps (note that there are many threads here discussing `Module` vs. `Block`)